# Google Cloud Tasks get response message

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I am using Google Cloud Tasks for asynchronous communication between HTTP microservices.
My task handler is a simple Java Spring application.
I am wondering if there is any way to get response message in case that a task gets failed using [GET TASK API CALL](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues.tasks/get). Currently I can see the HTTP response status in `lastAttempt.responseStatus.code` field but the `lastAttempt.responseStatus.details` field is empty. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Status) states `Any user-facing error message should be localized and sent in the google.rpc.Status.details field, or localized by the client.`
So I assume that I have to set the `lastAttempt.responseStatus.details` field with my response message, although I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: AFAIK, The response status is kept in case of error. In case of correct processing (HTTP response 2XX) you haven't this information. I recommend you to store the result elsewhere (in firestore) and to let your other process getting this value.

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere So in case of error is it possible to retrieve the error message from cloud tasks and not just the HTTP response code?

Comment: Yes, it seems that you can, in the last attempt field, you have a status object with the HTTP code and the message.

Comment: The message field contains the description of the HTTP response code. I want to retrieve my custom response error message.

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere Could you please help me with this issue? Any suggestion or to documentation to look at? I just want to get the response message in case of error.

Comment: I just tested, and you can't get your own message. It's GRPC standard message which is stored  by default. If you have GRPC endpoint, it could be different, but I havent this type of testable environment.